# how to remove side menu items from default home page on Sharepoint O365

Tags: office-365, menu-item, homepage

Could someone please let me know how I can remove this entire section of the homepage? I don't want my users to click on things they don't need. I am the Admin, so I can change anything, but I could find any toggle that turns this off.

Thanks!

[image: how to remove these items from the default homepage?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood from the description that you want to hide the *Site Contents* section which is placed just below to *Edit Links*. If this is correct then you can follow the below steps :

1. Go to **Site Settings**.
2. Click on **Navigation Elements** under **Look and Feel** (For SharePoint Online).
   / Click on **Tree View** under **Look and Feel** (For SharePoint On-Prem).
3. Disable **Enable Tree View** checkbox.
   [image]
4. Click **OK**.

Please do let me know if this helps. Don't forget to mark it as answer if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thank you! that did it. I was going mad looking for this toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a site page which has navigation placeholder in it. If you either hide it using custom css embeded on the page or create a webpart page which does not have left navigation as your home page.

If you would like to use the same home page, add a content editor webpart on the home page and add following css to it. You can then set the webpart properties to hide the webpart.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #sideNavBox { display: none; } //hide side nav
  #contentBox { margin-left: 0px; } //remove margin for main body content to use full width
</style>
```

Comment: That would work if I wanted to hide the entire left side, but I just wanted the Tree View. Abhishek above found the right setting.

Comment: If anyone wants to do this in 0365, do this: 1) Create a text file and put the text as shown above. Save as it as CSS. Add the file in the Sharepoint Site Assets container 2) open the page you want to remove the side nav. 3) Add the [Media and Content\Content Editor] webpart. Place the webpart at the bottom of the page (recommended). 4) Edit the webpart and insert the path to the CSS file as "/SiteAssets/<yourcssfilename>.css". 5) Save the webpart and webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer but for one thing. I would recommend using the "Embed Code" button or the Script Editor Web Part. These allow more functionality directly for editing on the webpage itself. The CEWP in more modern versions of SP require linking to a file as opposed to accepting the code directly within and running it.

[image: CEWP With code embedded]

As you can see, this is a CEWP with the code snippet, and it is just displaying it, not running it.

Comment: @sssready had the same answer. Thanks! But yours it is easier to copy and paste. Using this technique, you can hide a lot of elements from the page if you know the html ID name. Good post. ThanksS